# grive not synchronizing : sync time not long enough?

Tags: sync, grive

i have installed grive-tools as such :

```
      http://www.linuxtechi.com/mount-google-drive-in-ubuntu/
```

the synchronization is not working and my google drive folder remain empty.

I wonder if my google drive folder is not too big .
Any way of make the sync procedure longer?